# want to call Script from Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, community, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

When i run below code on button click event, it is not working.

```
<apex:page >
   <apex:form >
      <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryAvaWidget}"/>
      <div id="avalaraDiv" style="height:500px;width:1000px;">Div</div>
      <script>
         function test() {
         alert('in test function');
          $("#avalaraDiv").AvaWidget({
           InheritCss:true,
           AvalaraOnboardingObject: new AvalaraOnboarding("Test Connector","company_name","000000000", "address_line_1", "address_line_2", "address_line_3", "address_city", "", "state", "zipCode", "email", "firstname", "lastname", "phone"),                                                                                              
           onAvaTaxCompanyCreated: function (onboardingData) { alert(JSON.stringify(onboardingData)); }
            });
         }
      </script>
      <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
      <apex:commandButton value="Test" onclick="test()" />
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Can anyone help me to sort out please.

Comment: Try using an HTML button instead of an <apex:commandButton>. This may be a case of unexpected behavior of the VF component.

Comment: - Bhavesh, which jquery plugin you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use jQuery in your visualforce, either you have to load the jQuery js file as a Static Resource in salesforce or you can use the CDN's.
I think you are not able to use jQuery js file as a Static Resource in salesforce.
So, I suggest you to use CDN's Method.

You have to replace this code:

```
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryAvaWidget}"/>
```

with:

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
```

For more details you can also visit the following page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It s 100% possible to use a `Static Resource` to load `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I agree and know that we can use Static Resource to load jQuery. I was suggesting an alternate method of using CDN.